# Algorithm for generating subsets of finite sets

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, relations, computational-mathematics

Obviously there is no method to generate a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb N$ that, in analogue with diagonalizing elements in $\mathbb N^2$, gives an arbitrary number of arbitrary elements.

But is there a method to, one bye one, generate all subsets of $\mathbb Z_n$ without having to generate big subsets of $2^{\mathbb Z_n}$?

In order to investigate graphs and certain finite relations I would like to generate elements of sets as $2^{A\times B}$ without having  to consume enormous amounts of time and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since subsets of an $n$-set are in bijection with binary strings of length $n$, [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) should help here. Also, check out [Combinatorial Algorithms](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombinatorialAlgorithms.pdf) by Nijenhuis and Wilf, it has several algorithms similar to what you're looking for.